# JDBC MySql slow after first run

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I am trying a record consolidation job but facing a strange issue. Table has almost 10M rows. There are only 7 fields in the table of 50 char length (only one with upto 500 varchar). Its engine is InnoDB. First time, it runs quite fine but from second batch onward, DB slows down, I can see in MySql processlist that queries are taking too much time. Below log4j output will show the diff between first and second batch:

```
17:05:00.119 [PartialCDRService:165] [] Going to fetch records from DB
17:05:39.710 [PartialCDRService:168] [] Fetched records from DB. Total: 150000
17:06:55.614 [PartialCDRService:217] [] Record Arrays (recordsToAssembleAll) to consolidate size: 31135
17:06:56.303 [PartialCDRService:334] [] Record Arrays 6 Hrs Split to consolidate size: 31135
17:08:02.567 [PartialCDRService:1105] [] CDR Files Size going to be saved in Kafka: 11
17:08:03.321 [PartialCDRService:1134] [] Going to insert records in buff table :: 149995
17:08:18.729 [PartialCDRService:1136] [] Records inserted in buff table
17:08:18.729 [PartialCDRService:1139] [] Going to delete records from table :: 149995
17:08:20.747 [drDao:144] [] Deleted from partial_cdrs. Going to truncate partial_cdrs_buff
17:08:20.772 [PartialCDRService:1142] [] Records deleted from table
17:10:00.007 [PartialCDRService:165] [] Going to fetch records from DB
17:11:58.732 [PartialCDRService:168] [] Fetched records from DB. Total: 150000
17:13:02.918 [PartialCDRService:217] [] Record Arrays (recordsToAssembleAll) to consolidate size: 30826
17:13:03.572 [PartialCDRService:334] [] Record Arrays 6 Hrs Split to consolidate size: 30826
17:14:07.636 [PartialCDRService:1105] [] CDR Files Size going to be saved in Kafka: 11
17:14:08.060 [PartialCDRService:1134] [] Going to insert records in buff table :: 149999
17:25:23.316 [PartialCDRService:1136] [] Records inserted in buff table
17:25:23.316 [PartialCDRService:1139] [] Going to delete records from table :: 149999
17:27:16.408 [PartialCdrDao:144] [] Deleted from partial_cdrs. Going to truncate partial_cdrs_buff
17:27:16.653 [PartialCDRService:1142] [] Records deleted from table
17:27:16.655 [PartialCDRService:165] [] Going to fetch records from DB
```

PS: partial_cdrs_buff is a temporary table

I am closing connection,statements properly and using batches whereever possible. Don't want to make post verbose with Java code. Really stuck what could be wrong. I have tried several times, first run is fine but then DB hits get slower which is obvious from MySql 'show processlist' command. Any suggestion in this regard please

Comment: my first guess is that it actually your application that runs out of heap and slows down not the database. try raising the heap using -Xmx

Comment: I am running it with 16G memory and as I mentioned I can see db statements on MySql side taking longer than they should. MySql is the only service running on 24core 256G server.